# How to get two touch screen monitors to work on one computer

Tags: windows-vista, touchscreen

I just bought two new touchscreens.

I have a GeForce 9500 dual video card on a Vista 64bit machine. The video is working but the touch ability of the second screen is not working properly.

Screen one works with the touch, but when I use the second it moves the cursor on the first screen.  I have 2 USB cables hooked up but I think the computer only sees one.

Comment: Maybe some insight here.....http://www.touchscreens.com/support-technotes-multimon.html

Comment: It might help to know the type of touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

From this article by one maker of touch-screens, [Multiple Monitor Configurations](http://www.touchscreens.com/support-technotes-multimon.html) :

> Most of the touchscreens that we offer
>   now support multiple monitor
>   configurations in Windows (not
>   supported in Mac OSX at this time).
>   The touchscreen software driver will
>   typically determine if a touchscreen
>   can work in a multiple monitor system,
>   as well as how many monitors are
>   supported.

So it seems that it is a question of the video driver, whether it supports multiple touch-screens.
If that's the case, then the maximum you can do is update the video driver from the manufacturer's website, and hope.

Are both touch screens made by the same manufacturer ?